# javascript MediaRecorder API video no time information, no audio

Tags: javascript, mp4, video-capture, mediarecorder, getusermedia

I'm using a Chrome extension I made together with getUserMedia() and MediaRecorder API to record user screen and save the recording as mp4 video. My videos can't be opened in QuickTime, they can be opened in VLC, however there is no time information for them so they can't be rewinded.

Another problem is there is no audio

Here is the relevant part of the code I'm using:

```
function startRecording() {
    getScreenConstraints(function(error, screen_constraints) {
        if(error) {
            return alert(error);
        }

        console.log('screen_constraints', screen_constraints);

        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
        navigator.getUserMedia(screen_constraints, function(stream) {
            var video = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
            var audio = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
            navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, function (s) {
                audio = s.getAudioTracks()[0];
                stream.addTrack(audio);
                recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
                recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', onRecordingReady);
                recorder.addEventListener('stop', onStop);
                recorder.start();
            }, function(error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error, null, '\t'));
            });
        }, function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error, null, '\t'));
        });
    });
}

function onRecordingReady(e) {
    // e.data contains a blob representing the recording
    chunks.push(e.data);
}

function onStop(e) {
    console.log("data available after MediaRecorder.stop() called.");

    var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/mp4; codecs=mp4a.40.2' });
    saveData(blob, 'myVideo.mp4');
    console.log("recorder stopped");
}
```

I tried using a different codec with no luck

Answer (score 0):

> My videos can't be opened in QuickTime, they can be opened in VLC, however there is no time information for them so they can't be rewinded.

This is a known issue in browsers that has no solid resolution at this time.  With MP4, it has to do with the placement of the MOOV atom, and the fact that the MediaRecorder API already returned data to you that would have to be overwritten later.

> Another problem is there is no audio

Calling `addTrack` doesn't work right now.  You have to instantiate a new MediaStream with an array of tracks from the previous MediaStreams.

Comment: Could you add an example of instantiating a new MediaStream with an array of tracks to get audio to work?